# Angular material to Android app

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

How to convert angular website to android app? Is there any tool available to convert?
My website contains data,which is fetched through API calls only.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at [phonegap build](https://build.phonegap.com/) from Adobe.

I have used the service before which allows you to upload your web application source and then with some extra config files, launch and splash screen icons and images you can bundle your code up to native apps ready for distribution in app stores.

So no need for knowing any iOS or Android SDK tools, plus it means you can be pretty confident  your application will look the same cross platform/device